# Prove by Induction with Summation

Tags: summation, induction

Struggling with this , especially with the double summation; if anyone can help it be much appreciated!

$$\forall n \in \Bbb N : \quad \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{i=1}^n i(n − i + 1) .$$

It needs to be answered in the following format:

1- Prove for n=1

2- assume n=k

3- prove for k+1

Comment: In the LHS get rid of the inner summation by replacing it with the actual sum value. You must surely be knowing the formula for sum of numbers from 1 to $i$.(perhaps the formulas give it as sum of numbers from 1 to n; you have to tweak it)

Comment: @Markus Scheur: I understand the meaning your comment and its correctness. But it  has no information content.  It adds no value. This comment can be given to any answer for any question (almost). I am providing a way of proving. Whenever someone suggests a way of proof it does not mean any other approach would be futile. You should have suggested your method instead of posting this comment.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: I saw your answer just now. Definitely it answers the question. As OP mentioned "struggling with double summation" (his own words), I gave my suggestion on how one can get rid of one of the Sigma's.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: I do also see your point of view. Everything's fine. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you make a drawing in the plane of the couples $(i,c)$ that are being considered in the LHS sum, you'll see a triangle with apexes $(1,1)$, $(n,1)$ and $(n,n)$. In this triangle, you count the $c$'s vertically.

Here is a visualization of what is happening:

[image]

Now switch the two sums, using your drawing :
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{c=1}^n \sum_{i=c}^n c$$
but in the inner RHS sum, $c$ is a constant, and there are $n-c+1$ terms. So :
$$\sum_{c=1}^n \sum_{i=c}^n c = \sum_{c=1}^n c(n-c+1)$$
All that is left is to rename $c$ as $i$ :-)

I'd like to include the drawing, but don't know how to do. Maybe Tikz is implemented ?

Comment: Pictures are the best man.

Comment: I can't see a picture

Comment: @ChristophLiondas How about now?

Comment: @SimpleArt Can see it but I don't understand, how do I use this to prove by induction?

Comment: @ChristophLiondas The first order of the sums adds the first row left to right, the second row left to right, etc., which the second order of the sums adds top to bottom.  See that each arrow in the drawing signifies something you are going to add as part of the sum as well as the direction you are summing it.  This change of order in summations is applied in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{c=1}^i c 
&= \sum_{c=1}^n \sum_{i=c}^n c\qquad (1\le c\le i\le n)\\
&= \sum_{c=1}^n c\sum_{i=c}^n 1\\
&=\sum_{c=1}^n c(n-c+1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i(n − i + 1)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the identity for $n+1$:

- Left hand side
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \sum_{c=1}^i c =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{c=1}^i c+\sum_{c=1}^{n+1} c.$$
- Right hand side
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i(n+1 − i + 1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i(n− i + 1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(n− i + 1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i.$$

As the additional terms are the same, if the identity holds for $n$, then it holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here  is   an  answer  based upon induction. We show:

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{i=1}^n i(n - i + 1)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}

**Base step: $n=1$**

> We have to show
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^1 \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{i=1}^1 i(1 - i + 1)
> \end{align*}
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{LHS: }\qquad&\sum_{i=1}^1 \sum_{c=1}^i c =\sum_{c=1}^1 c=1\\
> \text{RHS: }\qquad&\sum_{i=1}^1 i(1 - i + 1)=1\cdot(1-1+1)=1
> \end{align*}
>
> the claim is valid for $n=1$.

**Induction hypothesis: $n=k$**

> We assume the validity of
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{i=1}^k i(k - i + 1)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Induction step: $n=k+1$**

> We have to show
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \sum_{c=1}^i c = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(k - i + 2)
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \sum_{c=1}^i c&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{c=1}^i c+\sum_{c=1}^{k+1} c\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(k - i + 1)+\sum_{c=1}^{k+1} c\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(k - i + 1)+\sum_{c=1}^{k+1} c\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(k - i + 1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(k - i + 2)\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we separate the summand with index $i=k+1$.
- In (3) we apply the induction hypothesis (1).
- In (4) we set the upper limit of the left sum to $k+1$ without changing anything since we are adding zero only.
- In (5) we change the name of the index $c$ to $i$ in the second sum.
- In (6) we merge the second sum into the first one.